# Open cv wont video capture an IP camera

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to capture from a streaming IP cam with username and password and port like so:`vs = cv2.VideoCapture('http://user:password@ipadress:port/video.cgi?.mjpg')`
but when I run the script I get this error in the cmd output:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (116) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://user:password@ipadress:port/video.cgi?.mjpg in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

things I tried:
-installing FFmpeg and directing it to the environment path
-trying different ports
-switching between HTTP and RTSP

obviously, I'm new. thank you.

Comment: The apparent cause is that OpenCV guesses `CAP_IMAGES` which stands for "OpenCV Image Sequence (e.g. img_%02d.jpg)". I suppose you could force `CAP_FFMPEG`.

Comment: thank you, but how can I force it?

Comment: You override the default argument.

Comment: I’m very sorry .. can you give me steps? I’m really new and don’t want to mess things up

Comment: Also new to Python; I'm just reading from the manual. You might be slightly over your head; perhaps you should try some easier projects while you're still learning.